# What will be the output of ANDing two objects in python

Tags: python, object

If we and two objects of the same type what is the expected output?
If we have two objects of the type Node as defined below

```
    class Node(object):
        def __init__(self,parent,k):
            self.key = k
            self.parent = parent
            self.left = None
            self.right = None
```

If we and objects of the type Node.What kind of output is expected? What will happen if we and objects of pre-defined type?

Comment: Do you mean `and` or `&`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`and` and `or` will evaluate to the last expression evaluated.  If the left side of an `and` is `True`, the right side is returned.  If the left side of an `or` is `False`, the right side is returned.

To define "truth" for classes, override `__len__` or `__nonzero__` as [described in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example

```
a = Node(1, None)
b = Node(1, 2)
result = a and b

print "a=%s" % id(a)
print "b=%s" % id(b)
print "result=%s" % id(result)
```

it prints

```
a=2329884
b=2311540
result=2311540
```

same is the result if we **and** pre-defined types.

The reason for this is that when object references are compared in boolean expressions then (by-default) they are checked for their existence, as if an object is **None** then it would yield **False** in a boolean expression and if it is not None then it would yield **True**.
For these sort of expressions, python checks if the first object is **None** then return **None** otherwise return the second object.
This expression is equivalent to this code sample

```
result = None if a is None else b
```

Similar is the case with **or**, which can be written as

```
result = b if a is None else a
```

or

```
result = a or b
```

Answer (score 0):

For the class `Node` you've defined there, the result of an `and` expression whose two operands are both instances of `Node`, is the second of the two operands. The result of an `or` is the first.

The reason for this is that all instances of `Node` are "truthy", meaning that they evaluate true in the context of logical tests. Furthermore, `and` returns its first operand if it's "falsey" otherwise the second, whereas `or` returns its first operand if it's "truthy" otherwise the second.

Other classes do not necessarily share this property of `Node`, that all instances are "truthy". For example an empty `list` is "falsey", as are the object `None` and the integer `0`. You can control this by implementing the special method `__nonzero__` in Python 2 or `__bool__` in Python 3. Alternatively you can control it by implementing `__len__` in both.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,parent,k):
        self.key = k
        self.parent = parent
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

a = Node(None,None)
b = Node(None,None)

a and b #will return the object in memory of b

if a and b: print("True")
>>> True
```

`and` will return the first object in that returns `False`, or the last object if all objects return `True`. `or` will return the first object that returns `True`, or the last object if all objects return `False`

Answer (score 0):

if you do:

```
A = Node(None, 'key1')
B = Node(None, 'key2')
```

then

```
A & B
```

will call

```
A.__and__(B)
```

Normally, this is not implemented, and will throw an exception. However, the class can define whatever kind of behaviour you want. (also see `rand`)

(as already noted,

```
A and B
```

is a *boolean* expression, will evaluate 'truth value' of A and of B, and then evaluate true/false from that. Normally, valid objects are True).